# Create a form container with Angular JS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am using Angular JS 1.5.6 and I would like to use only component and not directive.

I have more than 5 views using a form in my application. The style of the form is exactly the same in all the views, it is only the content of the form that changes. I have made components (input, button, etc..) and I would like to create a component for the form, it would be like a container component, in which I can put different components. In view A, the form will contain 1 button and 1 input, in view B the form will contain 2 button and 2 inputs, etc... But I don't know if it is possible to do it and how to dow it. I have [plnkered](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ODeci6ETIP3F8E9bqTo?p=preview) this. I would like to create a component for the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="myInput.js"></script>
  <script src="myButton.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>My form</h2>
    <form role="form">
      <my-input label="Firstname"></my-input>
      <my-input label="Lastname"></my-input>
      <my-button label="Submit"></my-button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two basic problems** need to be solved in your form container:

- Dynamic template for your form
- Handle summit should be run outside of your component.

I solve two problems by

- Read template via attrs property
- Pass handler function as a binding property

Code for **form component:**

```
  angular.module('MyApp').component('myForm', {
    templateUrl: function($element, $attrs) {
      return $attrs.template; // read template file from component attribute
    },
    controller: MyFormController,
    bindings: {
      label: '@',
      summitHandler: '&' // call to function outside of component via this property
    }
  });
```

**In MyFormController**, we need handle summit event by calling to summitHandler function passed via binding property:

```
function MyFormController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.summitForm = function(data) {
        // call handler with data summited
        var handler = ctrl.summitHandler();
        handler(data);
      }
}
```

That all for our form container component.

Now you can **add my-form** with:

```
<my-form label="Personal Info" template="myForm.html" summit-handler="ctrl.myFormHandler"></my-form>
```

Property **ctrl.myFormHandler** will be a function handling event in myCtl with:

```
ctrl.myFormHandler = function(data){
    console.log('receive test summit:' + data);
    ctrl.dataReceived = data;
}
```

[See it run here in Plunk.](https://plnkr.co/edit/aUEfoRiVY8zn8QGETVDf?p=preview)

Typing in the age field, you can see it will be passed to outside of form. Extend it with more features as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this project:

http://kelp404.github.io/angular-form-builder/

If you want to implement this yourself you will need to create a template dynamically and compile it before it's injected into the DOM.
This project can be useful:

https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile

It's directive but it will inject and compile your form elements (components or directives) for you:

```
<div bind-html-compile="formElements.input1"></div>
```